# std::set Unique Pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, std

```
struct departure_compare {
    bool operator() (const Leg* lhs, const Leg* rhs) const
    {
        return lhs->CurrentDepartureTime() < rhs->CurrentDepartureTime();
    }
};

class Station
{
    uint station_number_;
    std::set<Leg *, departure_compare> departure_legs_in_order_; // legs that depart from this station in order of departure time
public:
    Station(uint station_number) : station_number_(station_number) {};
    void addDepartureLeg(Leg *leg) { departure_legs_in_order_.insert(leg); };
    const std::set<Leg *, departure_compare>& DepartureLegs() const { return departure_legs_in_order_; };
    uint StationNumber() { return station_number_; };
};
```

I call this in a loop

```
Leg *new_leg = new Leg();
start_station->addDepartureLeg(new_leg); // start_station of type station
```

Now I recognized that sometimes, it doesn't insert the `new_leg` into this structure. Now I looked at the documentation which says that if it is already in the set structure then it doesn't insert `new_leg`. But how is this possible, if I always create a new pointer (Shouldn't the address be unique)?

Comment: Why the pointers and dynamic allocation?

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit Is it better to not dynamic allocate the Leg and use direct the structure inside the set without pointers? I thought this way i save memory

Comment: You're using _more_ memory this way, as well as making memory usage a lot less efficient.

Comment: But if i do Leg leg; and then i insert it into set, then set has to do a copy.

Comment: Or a move. Or the `Leg` can be constructed in-place. None of these scenarios put you in a situation where you are "saving memory" by using dynamic allocation instead.

Comment: Making copies (many of which the compiler will optimize as moves anyway) can be vastly more efficient than getting cache misses trying to chase pointers. Only optimize if performance _is_ a problem, and then, find what _really_ needs to be optimized before optimizing.

Comment: But i thought i read that the std library always make a copy and you can't construct the the Leg in-place? Do you have a link?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/emplace And, as I've said, even if you made a copy, it would _still_ be preferable to this. The cost of a _single_ temporary `Leg` instance? Not a big cost.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not determining uniqueness based on address, because  `departure_legs_in_order_` is declared as

```
std::set<Leg*,departure_compare> departure_legs_in_order_;
```

You've told the `set` to use `departure_compare` to determine which `Leg*` values are equal.  And they are equal if `Leg::CurrentDepartureTime()` is the same for both, in which case `insert` will return the existing entry.  And leak your pointer, if you don't notice, and forget to clean it up.